# VBA input data into Jquery table to submit a search on a site

Tags: jquery, html, vba

I am trying to figure out how to input data into an input box that is formatted as a Jquery table.

Below is the html snippet of the div of the table.

I cannot figure out how to reference the cell so I can input a string and then tell VBA to <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the string as a search.
Its not so much a question with the VBA side but how could I maybe define the value of the input box in the URL itself, if this could be done, it would make the whole process faster. I don't really have any experience with jquery format.

Also there is a screenshot of the page with the console up, unfortunately I cannot provide the url as it is a site that can only be accessed with company credentials. [Submission Page in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbVaR.png).

```html
<div id="params" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#params-fields">Fields</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#params-json">JSON</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#params-raw">Raw</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="params-fields" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr indent="0" name="expenseReceiptUri" parampropindex="0">
          <th><span class="paramLabel" style="left: 0px;">expenseReceiptUri</span></th>
          <td><span style="left: 0px;"><input type="text" placeholder="Uri (required)" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"></span><span class="snowman"
              style="left: 0px;">☃</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <td><input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" style="margin-top: 5px;"><span id="fields-notify" class="notification" style="display: none;"></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="params-json" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"> </div>
  <div id="params-raw" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"> <textarea id="rawParams"></textarea><input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitRaw"><input type="button" value="Format" id="formatRaw"><input type="button" value="From Fields →" id="fromFields"><input type="button" value="← To Fields" id="toFields">
    <div
      style="height:25px;">
      <div id="raw-notify" class="notification" style="display: none;">$nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the site, hard to say this will work for sure, but an approach like this is one way to do what you are after.

```
Public Sub enterData()

    'I'm assuming you already have an IE window

    'Find the Object
    Dim elements As Object
    Dim element  As Object

    'More about element selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
    Set elements = IE.Document.getElementByID("params-fields").getElementsByClassName("ui-autocomplete-input")

    'Iterate and check if has the 'placeholder' property with the 'Uri (required)' value
    For Each element In elements

        'see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp
        If element.getAttribute("placeholder") = "Uri (required)" Then
            element.Value = "Something goes here"
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That is similar to the method I tried a few days ago, It turns out the issue was how I was opening IE, rather than how I was calling that variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim element As HTMLLinkElement
Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
Dim b64 As String
Dim stoper As Integer

  'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "https://website.com"
'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ui-autocomplete-input")(0).Value = "submission value"
Set objInputs = objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each element In objInputs
If element.id Like "Submit" Then
element.Click
End If
Next
```

Here was my solution to get it done, it was an IE calling error, I changed

```
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
```

to

```
Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

which allowed my status wait to work, which in turn made the other stuff below work